# Seeking Open Source alternative to ArcGIS Navigator

Tags: android, open-source, gps, gis, navigation

I'm looking for an Open Source Android app for routing through our own network (mandatory). If possible, able to work offline.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

Heaps of options, and it does mention open source options. All will use OpenStreetMaps as the map and routing.

The Maps.Me solution looks pretty good - https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MAPS.ME
Navit seems to be more focused on in-car navigation, which might be more suitable depending upon what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but it's possible to use our own road network, not the OSM network? It's mandatory.

Comment: Almost all of those solutions will use open street map. However, check out this link here about submitting new 'roads' to open street map. https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/64067/how-add-new-road-in-openstreet-map